# Create an entry in google calendar based on an email

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api

Hi everyone I have been trying to know how to force gmail to add events to a calendar similar to how airbnb and airline tickets or even eventbrite does it, is there a standard email one can send or is it based on domain reputation to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about creating events in Google Calendar based on the content of an email (either inbound or outbound email) then Google already has these features called [Smart features & controls](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10079371). For trip information, you would need to set up your Google Account for [Google Travel](https://support.google.com/travel/answer/9098125).

Just take note how Google indexes these search terms or metadata only includes the first 1MB of a content on an email to identify if the smart features will automatically detect and suggest a creation of event based on the content of an email. [See info here](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462480#zippy=%2Cwhat-data-is-searched)

> " is there a standard email one can send or is it based on domain
> reputation to make it happen. "

Based on the question above, the domain reputation will only be relevant if you have integrated a third-party mail service within your Google Account, assuming you have Google Workspace, you can check this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=637889685467267203-1333442898&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en) for SMTP relay setup.

Other than that, using Google Calendar API only limits you based on your [Quota Limits for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

See also:

- [Avoid Calendar use limits - Google Workspace Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486)
- [Proper accounting with service accounts | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/quota#proper_accounting_with_service_accounts)
- [Limiting Requests Per User | Capping API usage | Cloud APIs | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_user)